# sublime text 3 error trying to parse file : unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages\User\Default

Tags: sublimetext3

when I put this code in my Default (Windows).sublime-keymap. Sublime text 3 report an error just like the title said. I don't know how to deal with that. 
Please help me. Thanks a lot.

> {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "delete_trailing_spaces"}

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86h4.png)

Comment: All of the key bindings in your file need to be separated by commas. I would check your file at the position the error message is telling you to make sure you did that.

Comment: Commas Works! Thanks a lot ! @OdatNurd

Answer (score 0):

maybe you lost one "," in the last.
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "delete_trailing_spaces"},